# Explicit specialization template member and typedef

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Found a curious emergent architecture (it wasn't designed intentionally but was created over time by adding up features) in code base, which looks like this, if dumbed down:

```
#include <iostream>
// Base class
template <class T>
struct Base {
   typedef T DataT;
   void foo();
};

// Parameter classes
struct A { int a[2]; };
struct B { int a[3]; };

// In original code Base<> had a complex list of arguments
typedef Base<A> ContainerA;
typedef Base<B> ContainerB;

// what allows to use ContainerA? It's a type name or explicit specialization?
// Class parameters, e.g. T, are unusable in this context  directly.
template<> void ContainerA::foo() {
    std::cout << "ContainerA " << sizeof(DataT) << std::endl;
}

template<> void ContainerB::foo() {
    std::cout << "ContainerB " << sizeof(DataT) << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    ContainerA a;
    ContainerB b;
    a.foo();
    b.foo();
}
```

Essentially, with multiple derived classes and complex template argument list this use of `typedef` saves time to type code and makes specialization declarations more readable. But which part of standard says that a typedef can be used in such way?

Code had partial support of C++11, no `using =` type declarations allowed.

Comment: `ContainerA` is not a type name, it's an alias of a type name, of a complete template specification.

Comment: @273K so it's legal to use type alias anywhere where complete template specification is expected? That thing works even in ancient compilers.

Comment: Yes, `typedef` is the same as `using`, but can't be used for partial specializations, only full specializations are allowed. *Sorry, the first my comment is using the wrong word **specification** due to Gboard completion*.

Comment: A specialization is basically just `template<>` followed by some valid declaration. That is a valid way to define a member of a non-template class, so it's not ill-formed in that regard. And I'd be really surprised if it *didn't* work. Because then the only recourse would be macros, which would have been shameful.

Comment: There is at least one place where a type alias like this is not allowed to substitute for the template: in an explicit instantiation. `template class ContainerA;` is not allowed, but `template class Base<A>;` is.